# Check if an element is removed java

Tags: java, list

I'd like to check if an element is removed from a list using java.

The first method is to remove the element, and then I create a new method to check if it is deleted:

```
public void removeElement(int index){
    try { 
        element.remove(index);
    } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("Please enter an index number between 0 and "+e);
    }
}

public void removeElement (Element element) {
    boolean removed;
    if(element==null) {
        removed=true;
    }
    else {
        removed=false;
    }
```

No error appears, just a warning saying "The value of the local variable `removed` is not used."

Comment: It's indeed the case. The value is not used, you should return it, or make it a class variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the list :

```
List<Element> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

You could change your `removeElement()` method to the following:

```
public boolean removeElement (Element element) {
   return myList.remove(element);
}
```

Here if the element was successfully removed, it would return `true` else it would remove `false`. (Also since this a custom class you need to override the `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods.

---

You are receiving this warning

> "The value of the local variable removed is not used."

because in `removeElement (Element element)` you are not returning the value of the variable `removed` so its value is *not being used* anywhere.

Comment: @jdk : Do consider upvoting the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list.contains()` to check if the `Element` exists in the `List`. But for that to work, your class `Element` needs to have `equals` and `hashcode()` methods over-ridden because `contains` internally uses them to check for the equality.